# React update state variable with JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

App.js:

```
function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const searchDB = () => {
      fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8443/subColumns/5/?key=fc257229-8f91-4920-b71f-885403114b35", {
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'include'
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
          setItems(json);
        })
  console.log({items});
    }
    searchDB();
  }, [])
```

I need to keep the json response in a state varibale because in the future, the API request will nt be hard coded and I expect the user will make multiple API requests without refreshing, and the results will have to be mapped to different components. At the moment, trying to print {items} to the console returns an empty array.

Comment: That is because you are console loggin before you get the response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `setItems` is the asynchronous method, you can't get the updated value immediately after setItems. You should use another `useEffect` with dependency to see the value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(items);
}, [items]);
```