# It seems Axios does not update the state when use with async and await

Tags: reactjs, axios

How do I update the state data immediately when I use Axios with async and await? It seems not updating the state data immediately. Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciated. Here is the code sample:

```
const[dbdata,setDBData] = useState([])  


  useEffect(async() => {
        const response = await Axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/posts/allpost', {withCredentials:true})
        setDBData(response.data)
    
    }, [])

    const GetPost = async(id) =>{
        const response = await Axios.put('http://localhost:5000/api/posts/getPost',{postId:id}, {withCredentials:true})
        const getData = dbdata.map(item => {
            if(item._id==response._id){
                return response
            }
            else{
                return item
            }
           
        })
        console.log(getData)
        setDBData(getData)
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64982687/react-update-state-variable-with-json-data/64982721#64982721 - does this answer your question?

Comment: do console.log and check

Comment: Don't use async callback useEffect(async()<--

Answer (score 1):

useEffect(async () => ...) are not supported, but you can call an async function inside an effect.

Try:

```
useEffect(() => {
 
  const GetPost = async(id) =>{
       const response = await Axios.put('http://localhost:5000/api/posts/getPost',{postId:id}, {withCredentials:true});
       const getData = dbdata.map(item => {
           if(item._id==response._id){
              return response;
           }
           else{
              return item;
           }
               
        })
        console.log(getData);
        setDBData(getData);
  }
   GetPost();
}, [])
```

EDIT:

OR:

```
useEffect(() => {
   GetPost();
}, []);

const GetPost = async(id) =>{
       const response = await Axios.put('http://localhost:5000/api/posts/getPost',{postId:id}, {withCredentials:true});
       const getData = dbdata.map(item => {
           if(item._id==response._id){
              return response;
           }
           else{
              return item;
           }
               
        })
        console.log(getData);
        setDBData(getData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I call the GetPost function in the button onClick since it is in the useEffect? Thanks again

Comment: Move GetPost outside of useEffect.

Comment: create another `state` that gonna trigger the `useEffect` then. Eg: `const [click, setClick] = useState(false)`. Then in `useEffect(() => GetPost, [click])`. What left is update the `click` in `onClick` event like so: `onClick={() = > setClick(true)}`. Put the `onClick` event on the `button` that you want

Comment: I changed from async to non async but the state data still not updated?  const GetPost = (id) =>{
        Axios.put('http://localhost:5000/api/posts/getPost',{postId:id}, {withCredentials:true}).then(response => {
               const getData = dbdata.map(item => {
                if(item._id==response._id){
                    return response
                }
                else{
                    return item
                }
               
            })
            setDBData(getData)
        })        
    }

Comment: Try with setDBData([...getData]).

Comment: hi lissettdm; can I use useEffect twice? if you look at my posted question, I have already used the useEffect(). Can I still use useEffect again in the GetPost()? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I  console.log([...likeData]) and still get the previous state as before after I click the button

Comment: I need to refresh the page then I could see the state data changes.

Comment: Are you sure this condition  item._id==response._id is true at some point?

Comment: hi lissettdm, thanks for reminding me to check on the response._id. In fact, it should have been response.data._id. It is solved. Thanks again lissettdm.

Comment: I am happy to help